# error_get_last() returns null after set_error_handler(); php 7.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, php-7

The next code:

```
$a["x"];//should trigger notice
var_dump(error_get_last());//return the error array
```

runs perfectly and returns an error array.
but when I use set_error_handler it returns `null`

```
function _do_nothing(){}
set_error_handler('_do_nothing');

$a["x"];//should trigger notice
var_dump(error_get_last());//return null
```

This code works perfectly on PHP5.4 I had changed 3 month ago to PHP7 and since then I am getting nulls in `error_get_last()`
I am using a shutdown function to check if an error has occured and if so to send it to the developer.

1. Is there a way to make this code run in PHP7? and make error_get_last() works with set_error_handler()?
2. Any other ideas for workaround? and make a shutdown function get the last error? I am using CodeIgniter, and prefer not to hack their internal code.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the PHP version. This helped me understanding why my code from 4 years ago suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior because in your example the error is already handled by the `_do_nothing()` function, so the `error_get_last()` returns `null`

if you remove `set_error_handler('_do_nothing')` the error won't be handled anymore and you will get the last error again

```
function _do_nothing(){}
//set_error_handler('_do_nothing');

$a["x"];//should trigger notice
var_dump(error_get_last());//return array() "Undefined variable: a"
```

This behavior is the same in PHP5 as in PHP7

Comment: However, there is a big difference for `error_get_last()` if it is called within the error handler. If you try to catch errors (e.g. parse erorrs) with a custom function, e.g. `_do_nothing()` and call `error_get_last()` within that function `error_get_last()` would return the error in PHP 5.*. However, in PHP 7.* it would return `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, it is more complicated. Actually the different behavior of PHP 5 and 7 requires registering a custom exception handler. I documented this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728546/error-get-last-returns-null-in-php-7-when-a-custom-exception-handler-is-set