# PHP 7.0.20: Exception has Code 0

Tags: php, exception, php-7

I get an exception with errorcode 0 but I don't why? The text/message of the exception is "Call to a member function getId() on null" but the attribute "code" is 0. Why is it 0 and not a real number? All other exception has a correct errorcode.

Is it a bug or a misconfiguration in my php.ini?

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Exception on what part of code? Or function?

Comment: In a class there is that error and in my own exceptionhandler I want to handle all exceptions which there thrown in my application. In the handler I use $exception->getCode() and $exception->getMessage()

Comment: `Call to member function foo on null` is a fatal error.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: Ah, so I've no chance that a fatal error has a code? or how can I check if it's a fatal error? I use in my fatalhander the function "error_get_last()" but this is always null, but in my old php version 5.6 it works fine :)

Comment: You can check that the object you're trying to use, isn't null before using it. If it is, you can throw an exception.

Answer (score 7):

Exceptions don't always have codes. When one is not explicitly defined, the error code defaults to `0`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php - an exception will default to a message of `""`, a code of `0`, and a previous exception of `NULL`.

```
try {
    throw new Exception('Hello!');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getCode(); // prints 0
}
```

Same thing with things like PHP errors:

```
try {
    $foo = new stdClass;
    $foo->fooBar();
} catch(Error $e) {
    echo $e->getCode(); // prints 0 too
    echo $e->getMessage(); // prints "Call to a member function fooBar() on null"
}
```

Comment: okey, but it in my case it is a php exception, so I hoped that I get an errorCode or an ExceptionType like "E_ERROR". But nothing :)

Comment: @user3388366 PHP's built-in `Error` class has the identical signature. http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php The error code for a fatal error appears to be `0`.

Comment: Ah, so I've no chance that a fatal error has a code? or how can I check if it's a fatal error? I use in my fatalhander the function "error_get_last()" but this is always null, but in my old php version 5.6 it works fine :)

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize that was a recoverable error.

Comment: Yep, this one's recoverable. I misspoke - you can't catch a fatal error, but this one's non-fatal. Edited an example of it into my answer.

Comment: okey but why is "error_get_last()" null in my handler?     public function fatalHandler(){
        $error = error_get_last();
        if($error) {
            $this->errorHandler($error['type'],$error['message'],$error['file'],$error['line']);
        }
    }

Comment: Because you *handled* the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915174/error-get-last-returns-null-after-set-error-handler-php-7-0 :-)